# How to get notifications on the active monitor in GNOME Shell 3.28.3

Tags: gnome, multiple-monitors, gnome-shell, notification, notification-area

How to get notifications appear on the active monitor in GNOME Shell 3.28.3 (Ubuntu 18.04) when two monitors are connected as extended displays (one primary and the other as secondary)?

Currently, I am missing a lot of notifications, as I am more focused on the secondary monitor and notifications are displayed only on the primary monitor (mostly low battery notifications).