# GNOME Notifications on all monitors

Tags: 18.04, multiple-monitors, gnome-shell, notification

Is it possible to show GNOME notifications, like the one on screenshot, on every monitor? I'm using three monitors so sometimes I miss notifications that appear on the default screen.

[image]

Comment: same as https://askubuntu.com/questions/1149094/how-to-get-notifications-on-the-active-monitor-in-gnome-shell-3-28-3