# Gnome notifications and multiple monitors

Tags: gnome, multiple-monitors, notification, 21.10

I have dual monitors on an Ubuntu 21.10 system with Gnome version 40.4.0.  One monitor is directly in front of me and the other is to the side, which I rarely look at.  Gnome notifications like a new e-mail in Thunderbird or a message from Whatsapp Web appears on the other monitor and not the one in front of me.

Is there a way to make the notifications appear on the monitor in front of me.  What is causing it to choose the other monitor?

I've seen a similar question for [Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1149094/how-to-get-notifications-on-the-active-monitor-in-gnome-shell-3-28-3) or for notifications to appear on [all monitors](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1181793/gnome-notifications-on-all-monitors).  However, neither question has any replies.

I'm glad I'm not the only one wondering about this.  Would anyone have a solution?  Thank you!

Comment: Don't have a solution. But I came across this [issue](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/-/issues/6775) requesting a feature to display notifications on multiple monitors depending on severity. And a dev seems to take the request into account. Perhaps you can consider issuing another request about this seemingly simpler addition. Apparently, there is an ongoing [effort](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2019/05/gnome-shell-new-notifications) as of December 2023 to develop the notifications.

Comment: Thanks for this!  I'm now on an Ubuntu 23.10 system and the notifications are now on the screen in front of me.  I'm still not sure what's causing it to appear on my main screen now; feels like it's random and, at random, the problem is fixed...  But what you put up sounds interesting -- thank you for bringing it to my attention!  I'll look into the links.

Comment: @Johan the *answer* is not suitable it's a link only.  And OP indicates that this is an issue that comes and goes without any real way to reproduce it.  As such, I've simply closed this question as "can't be reproduced' because Ray can't reproduce it reliably.

Comment: @ThomasWard guess what; I can reproduce the issue, but leave that aside. Why did you delete my question to you? I just wanted to make you aware that there are similar questions on askubuntu that you might want to moderate (read: close) as well. Good luck with your work.

Comment: @Johan Read up about how comments are on the site.  The post is **already closed** and you don't specifically state reproduction requests, and all you do is *links* in your answer, which in turn makes your answer a "link only answer".  If you had included specifics about the issue or the developers' response your post would not have been deleted, because link-only answers are considered **non-answers**.

Comment: @ThomasWard let me be clearer: you deleted my comment - why? (I am not asking why you deleted my answer to this question). And also let me provide you the links to similar questions that I assume you would like to close because they are not relevant to askubuntu (your initial reason for closing): 1) https://askubuntu.com/questions/1149094/how-to-get-notifications-on-the-active-monitor-in-gnome-shell-3-28-3 2) https://askubuntu.com/questions/1181793/gnome-notifications-on-all-monitors

Comment: @Johan This is **NOT** the proper forum to bring questions about why we delete comments up.  If you have that kind of question, you should use Meta to ask questions about the site.  HOWEVER, "the comment served no more useful purpose" and "was not needed anymore" remains the same answer.